# Firebase hosting redirects to stop page

Tags: firebase-hosting

I have deployed a Firebase app internally at work, which is accessible just fine in the network. But if you want to access it outside the work (ex at home) then it will redirect to a 'stop page' which you normally see when you try to access torrent or any other blocked websites.

How can I solve this?

[image]

Some more info:

```
NET::ERR_CERT_COMMON_NAME_INVALID
Subject: *.services.belgium.be

Issuer: QuoVadis Europe SSL CA G1

Expires on: 7 May 2020

Current date: 21 May 2019
```

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because SO can't offer legal advice. I recommend you follow the steps listed on the stop page.

Comment: Can you clarify your question? If you are using "firebase-hosting", which your tag indicates, how is it "internal[] at work"?

Comment: @abraham I don't need legal advice, I'm wondering what might have caused this as it's just a Firebase application.

Comment: @Prisoner I meant, it's deployed to Firebase hosting in the network of my company I work for so maybe something went wrong there; I don't know. It's weird as there's no reason for it to be blocked by my country.

Comment: Firebase hosting isn't on your corporate network.

Comment: The same thing happened here: https://github.com/gatanaso/multiselect-combo-box/issues/34#issuecomment-516830878 Is it possible that Belgium is blocking *.firebaseapp domain?

Comment: @MartinVysny It's strange to say the least, never had problems but then again it had been a while since I used it before this project so might have changed in the meantime.